# Batch file not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file

1. I've 2 server, **server1** and **server2**.
2. In **server1** I've 1 batch script, **A1.bat**.
3. In **server2** I've 2 batch script, **A2.bat** and **A3.bat**.
4. *A1.bat file is calling A2.bat* and *A2.bat calling A3.bat file*.
5. When I'm executing A2.bat file from server2, it's working fine. It's calling A3.bat file.
6. But When I'm executing A1.bat file from server1 then A2.bat file got executed successfully but failed to call A3.bat file.

In A1.bat:

> ```
>    @echo off
>    Call \\server2\full_path\A2.bat
> ```

In A2.bat:

> ```
>    @echo off
>    echo Hello
>    Call A3.bat
> ```

In A3.bat:

> ```
>    @echo off
>    echo World
> ```

I don't want to change the code present in A2.bat. If I give full path in A2.bat to call A3.bat, then it's working fine.

In A2.bat:

> ```
>    @echo off
>    echo Hello
>    Call \\server2\full_path\A3.bat
> ```

Is there any possibility to change in code A1.bat (like using psexec or anything) to execute A3.bat by calling A2.bat from server1 using A1.bat.

Please help! Thank you in advance :) !

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your question and reference the servers by something like *Server1* and *Server2* instead of **AB** and **CD**. As you know `CD` is also a  CMD command and they can be confused with each other when answering or commenting on your question. Besides, the information you provided are **not consistent** : If **A1.bat** and **A2.bat** are located in "CD server" then how are you *successfully* calling them by `\\AB\full_path\A2.bat` or `\\AB\full_path\A3.bat`.

Comment: And `psexec` is meant for remotely executing the scripts on the target server (CD Server), it is different from calling a remote file on "CD Server" and run it locally on "AB Server". So you should first make clear what your intention is

Comment: I have A2.bat and A3.bat already. I'm using this files for long time and running only on server2. Now there is a requirement to use the same batch file (A2.bat, which is internally calling A3.bat) from another server (server2). So I need to create a new batch file in server2 (A1.bat) which can call A2.bat.

Comment: When using UNC paths to execute a batch file the working directory becomes `C:\Windows`.  It **LITERALLY** tells you that when you execute the batch file.

Comment: So basically you have a non-working code you don't want to change, but you want it to work... sounds quite impossible to me...

Comment: If your intention is to avoid *Hard Coded* path in **A2.bat**, It can be done, but not by keeping **A2.bat** untouched! And [AlexP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412986/alexp) have already provided the answer. `%~dp0` refers to the directory of the currently executing batch file, so as long as those batch files reside on the same server, you can always address **A3.bat** relative to the location of **A2.bat** and/or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

UNC paths, such as `\\AB\full_path`, are not supported as current working directories. Therefore `%CD%` is not set in `A2.bat`, and the relative reference to `A3.bat` cannot be resolved. You *must* modify `A2.bat`.

There are multiple ways to do it; the best is to simulate a relative reference:

```
call "%~dp0A3.bat"
```

Comment: UNC default paths are turned off by default as they used to crash older programs.[11] 

The Dword registry value DisableUNCCheck at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor[11] allows the default directory to be UNC. CD command will refuse to change but placing a UNC path in Default Directory in a shortcut to Cmd or by using the Start command. start "" /d \\127.0.0.1\C$ "cmd /k" (C$ share is for administrators). 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut

Comment: @CatCat, The OP is not trying to directly invoke the remote batch file. but he is calling the remote batch file from a locally invoked batch file. So the initial current directory is not an issue here.